# how to download java Sphinx4 package

Tags: java

```
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer;
```

Hello guys!
Can you please help me to find these packages, i have download few packages but, when i extract the zip file there is nothing, please share a link if you know how to download it, 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the specific .jar [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/edu/cmu/sphinx/sphinx4-core/5prealpha-SNAPSHOT/sphinx4-core-5prealpha-20160628.232526-10.jar).

In general, [this search](https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~edu.cmu.sphinx) of the Sonatype Maven repo will find the stuff you should need. Not 100% sure about the release version, but hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" Property exception component:'acousticModelLoader' property:'location' - Can't locate resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us
edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.InternalConfigurationException: Can't locate resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManagerUtils.getResource(ConfigurationManagerUtils.java:468)

Comment: OK, so now your compilation problem is fixed, but it looks like sphinx is not correctly configured. Unfortunately, I don't know that software only Java. I would recommend asking a separate question about this problem, as it's not related to your original question.

Comment: Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)